# Fixed position element within a bootstrap 4 column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to have a bar sit at the bottom of the users screen, but only within a column. I can use `position:fixed; bottom:0;` if I want the element to stretch across the entire screen, but I can't figure out how to make the bar stay within the column. See picture for example

[image]

In the above picture, I want the Like, Comment, Share box to always be at the bottom of the users screen, but stay within the column it's in.

I'm using bootstrap 4, and you can see the website here: https://www.arelplane.com/@arelenglish

EDIT:

HTML of page

```
<div class='container-fluid user-profile'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-3 col-12 d-none d-md-block remove-lr-padding' id='sticky-sidebar'>
      <div class='row mt-5 mb-5 align-center'>
        <div class="col-12">
          Some text
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row social-module">
        <div class="col-4">
          Like
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          Comment
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          Share
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-9 col-12 remove-lr-padding' id='user-map'>
      <div class="user-map" id="cesiumContainer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.social-module {
  background-color: blue;
  // position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Edit 2:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/arel/9t3tnhzt/3/

Comment: so Like Comment Share would be outside of the white box, and below the container with box shadow, but still aligned with the column left of the dark Tennesee map?

Comment: is your parent wrap position: relative; ?? and child wrap (the bar) position: absolute? with left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;

Comment: Code, code, where's the code??

Comment: @AkinHwan this is a mockup of how it should look, with placeholder icons. So the white box with the like/comment/share should stick to the bottom of the screen, but stay constrained in the left sidebar column.

Comment: you may want to give us the exact page this is occuring on? or better yet, create a simplified subset of this entire website where we can just mess with this problem

Comment: @AkinHwan good idea. Working on a Fiddle

Comment: @AkinHwan added a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/arel/9t3tnhzt/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you make the bar stay at the bottom of the column:

`<div class="d-flex align-items-end">...</div>`

Alternatively, add the `align-items-end` class to that column.

No need for custom css in Bootstrap 4.

Here's a working example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid user-profile">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 remove-lr-padding" id="sticky-sidebar">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-12 bg-warning" style="min-height: 100vh;">
                    <p>Feature requests? Questions?</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate temporibus assumenda molestias laborum ipsam quisquam, nisi, aspernatur quia, ratione ipsum illo cum exercitationem nostrum dolor corrupti ducimus sunt provident harum. Eum, ullam id! Adipisci perspiciatis reiciendis minus quisquam culpa nobis voluptatem suscipit iusto dolores hic ab impedit incidunt rem labore praesentium, sed itaque voluptates distinctio vero temporibus quia atque magni ratione. Ratione, sit maiores asperiores architecto deserunt ducimus dignissimos? Error doloremque reiciendis repellendus esse dolor at expedita non. Ipsum maxime optio quasi, ratione pariatur excepturi aperiam. Dolores nisi magni est suscipit placeat nobis quaerat fugit culpa laboriosam, quam autem aut nesciunt fuga reiciendis dolor omnis doloremque ab corporis dicta adipisci eos amet ipsa. Qui beatae possimus pariatur nemo ducimus autem, architecto officia libero nisi quo, a earum repellendus explicabo cumque quidem consequatur sapiente ipsam molestias molestiae, nostrum sed nesciunt neque. Ex accusantium inventore quam! Commodi tempora eligendi possimus nam ut similique quidem, rem enim, quo quisquam autem accusantium! Suscipit error a quidem adipisci. Repellat maxime nesciunt id quasi deleniti, consectetur, est eius commodi doloremque odit, fugiat! Consequatur modi distinctio reiciendis natus et quibusdam eum doloribus temporibus delectus obcaecati laboriosam earum, ad eveniet! Ea, necessitatibus perferendis, nostrum aperiam saepe voluptates reiciendis odit, quis porro ipsa omnis ab iste doloribus, cupiditate nobis eos enim cum molestias facilis laudantium ex. Hic at impedit in alias.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row social-module position-sticky fixed-bottom m-0 w-100 py-2 bg-primary">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                        Like
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                        Cmnt
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                        Share
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 remove-lr-padding" id="user-map">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just added the `h-100` class to the row and then added the `position-sticky` class to the other row.

Oh, and I ripped out your margins. :-)

Comment: I can't get your solution to work. I've created a simple version in a fiddle if you want to take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/arel/9t3tnhzt/1/

Comment: Does this do the job?

Comment: Oh, and it's the `text-center` class you want. Not "align-center". I mean, if you meant to center the contents inside.

Comment: I'm trying to get the social-module to sit at the bottom of the users screen in the sidebar, so when you scroll up and down, you see social-module. The problem is that if I use the conventional methods to keep it at the bottom of the screen, it stretches to the full width of the screen. You can uncomment line 14 I believe in the CSS in the fiddle to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Aha! You always want it to sit at the very bottom, no matter what, right? Now, I understand! One moment...

Comment: In your fiddle, can you fill the right column and also the upper left with some dummy content? I mean, put so much content that it creates vertical scrollbars. That  will help me understand exactly how you want the social bar to behave because there are different options.

Comment: Also, will you have a footer? What if the social bar overlays the footer? Is that desirable?

Comment: Updated: https://jsfiddle.net/arel/9t3tnhzt/5/

I do have a footer, and I suppose ideally the social-module would stop at the bottom of the side-bar as the user scrolls.

Comment: Well, in this case, my updated code should give you what you want. Check it out and let me know.

Comment: And if my updated code doesn't do what you want, please describe how the social bar needs to behave instead with various amounts of content inside the sidebar.

Comment: In other words, do you want it to float at the bottom of the screen inside that column (potentially overlaying other content inside) or do you want it the way it is in my most recent code snippet?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be doing anything. I updated my fiddle with your changes: https://jsfiddle.net/arel/9t3tnhzt/6/ 

Here is an example of what I want, but with the social-module expanding beyond the side-bar. https://jsfiddle.net/arel/9t3tnhzt/7/

The social-module should stay at the bottom of the users screen, not at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Well, your fiddle doesn't display my code properly. That's for sure. Rip out all of your own css and use only the code + css from my code snippet.

Comment: You said: "Here is an example of what I want, but with the social-module expanding beyond the side-bar." Question: Expanding beyond the sidebar but **in which direction** beyond the sidebar?? This is wide open to interpretation!

Comment: So, it seems to me that this: https://jsfiddle.net/arel/9t3tnhzt/7/ produces exactly what you want. I have not the slightest idea what else you might want...

Comment: It's either this sticky social bar that you have here: https://jsfiddle.net/arel/9t3tnhzt/7/ OR the version that I have in my most recent code snippet. I have absolutely no idea what else besides these 2 versions you might want.

Comment: Ok, the problem with that fiddle is that the social-module is full width. It is under the #user-map (pink) section, so you can't see the part that is extending beyond the side-bar. You can tell the social-module is full width because only the like text is visible. The other text is hidden under the #user-map section. 

Try commenting out line 13 of the CSS and pressing run, and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: OK, so, first of all: You DO want the social bar to float and you DO want it to overlay other content inside the sidebar, correct? By float I mean constantly hover at the bottom of the screen and not at the bottom of the page.

Comment: How about using this version: https://jsfiddle.net/arel/9t3tnhzt/7/ but instead of width= 100% have the width set to 33.3% and be done with it?

Comment: Correct, and setting the width is an option, but it wont work in all situations because it's a responsive website, and the sidebar isn't always 33% of the page.

Comment: OK, then what should happen on smaller screens?

Comment: The social-bar should resize with the sidebar, like any other content within the sidebar.

Comment: Alright, check out my updated code snippet. I hope this now does the trick. The social bar items will stack up at the medium breakpoint.

Comment: I guess one part of the confusion was because you hadn't any responsive classes added to the social bar items. So, I added them for you now. :-)

Comment: This is almost perfect, except, if there isn't enough content in the sidebar, the social-module doesn't sit at the bottom of the screen, it sits below the last thing on the screen.

Comment: OK, I updated my code snippet to fix that. Also note that I've now removed all of your custom css and it still works using native Bootstrap classes alone. Pretty cool huh? :-)

Comment: Most of the relevant magic is now done by these classes: `row social-module position-sticky fixed-bottom m-0 w-100 py-2 bg-primary`

Comment: Well, the `social-module` class is now obsolete. :-)

Comment: I just had to make one adjustment. Because many rows may exist in the side bar, I put a wrapper div around the entire thing with a min-height. Thanks for the help!